# How to set height to mui-datatable with responsive="scroll"

Tags: mui-datatable

I need to have fixed table body height to firstly show up on my whole page nicely and secondly to not change height when I choose filters and filter tags are added to header.

I have real trouble finding solution. My best guess I should overwrite MUIDataTable.responsiveScroll class but it does nothing when I change `minHeight:'80vh'` for exmple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to override the MUIDataTable.responsiveScroll.  This is what I did for expanding to full size of page

```
createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
      MUIDataTable: {
        responsiveScroll: {
          maxHeight: 'none',
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

You can add other styles there if you want a minimum height.

Comment: Any Idea how to implement the same with Mui 5 and Mui-datatables 4.0.0?